# Clone form without saving values

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
<h1 class="form__title">Рекомендуемые круизы</h1>
<div class="wrapper-form" id="form">


    <div class="wrapper-inputs">
        <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">

            <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">

            <input type="text" id="portInput"name="portInput"class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required >
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">

            <input type="text" id="linkInput" name="linkInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="form__btn">Отправить</button>
<button id="new">добавить форму</button>
```

Im new in js and don't know how to clone form without saving values.
Could someone help please
**UPDATE**: These answers add more forms than 1

Comment: Suggested answers should do the trick. You can read more about 'clone' here: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ Don't forget to include jquery into your page.

Comment: @c00ki3s yes they clone the form but when i press button add it adds much more forms than one. How can add only 1 form?

Comment: You can solve this using unquie identifiers. Add an id tag to your form and clone it using that id. Remember jquery uses a '#' character for id selectors. This will select and clone a form with a specific identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone` with form `id/class` and append where ever you want or do whatever you do after clone.

```js
var html = $('.form').clone();
$('#appendClone').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
  <h1 class="form__title">Рекомендуемые круизы</h1>
  <div class="wrapper-form" id="form">


    <div class="wrapper-inputs">
      <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">

        <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">

        <input type="text" id="portInput" name="portInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">

        <input type="text" id="linkInput" name="linkInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="form__btn">Отправить</button>
  <button id="new">добавить форму</button>
</form>

<div id='appendClone'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some thing like this:

```
$('#new').click(function() {
    var clone = $('.form').clone('#form');
    $('.form').append(clone);
});
```

Comment: Yes but it adding more than one forms

Answer (score 0):

## Update

This demo will:

- Clone the first form whenever `button#new` is clicked.
- Resets all values within clone.
- It assigns unique ids to all tags within the clone.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Outer counter
var A = 0;
// Inner counter
var B = 0;
// Original <form>
var first = $('.form:first');
// Click button#new
$('#new').on('click', function(e) {
  // Increment outer
  A++;
  // Clone the first <form> append to <body> reference it
  var dupe = first.clone(true, true).appendTo('body');
  // Reset the clone
  dupe[0].reset();
  /* 
  Find all tags within the clone that has an id
  Get each id and add the current counter values
  */
  dupe.find('[id]').each(function() {
    B++;
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).attr('id', id + A + B);
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
  <h1 class="form__title">Рекомендуемые круизы</h1>
  <div class="wrapper-form">
    <div class="wrapper-inputs">
      <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">
        <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">
        <input type="text" id="portInput" name="portInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-inputs_name">
        <input type="text" id="linkInput" name="linkInput" class="wrapper-inputs__name-input" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="form__btn">Отправить</button>
  <button id="new" type='button'>добавить форму</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ty for answer, this code clons form, but every time when I press button add it multiplies on 2 and adding more forms. But I need only 1

Comment: @JohnMozley Ok review Demo 1

Comment: No i need that after every pressing button only 1 form must be added

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the fact that it's cloning the **class `.form`**. So now the only form being cloned is **form:first** and now it insures that all ids are unique. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've made a very simple example on how you can manipulate with dynamically created  forms using jquery. It's not the cleanest sample but it will help you understand some basics on how jquery works with selectors, dynamic elements, events, event listeners etc.

We start of by creating a simple html page that will have two containers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container_A">
          <form id="form_A">
            <div id="form_title"></div>
            <div>First name:</div><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
            <div>Last name:</div><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br>
            <input id="form_submit" class="button-submit" type="button" value="Submit!" />
            <br><br>
          </form>
        </div>
        <button id="clone_form" type="button">Clone!</button>
        <br><br>
        <div id="container_B">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Container A will hold our primary form that we want to clone and
  manipulate with later.
- Container B will receive all cloned forms on triggered button click events.
- For the form submit button I'll use a simple input tag of type
  button. I don't want to use an input of type submit since that one
  will refresh my page and all the forms and data will get lost every time I trigger it.

Now let's add a simple jquery script with event listeners.

```
    //I load my functions when document is ready (when page has finished loading)
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //I create a very simple index for my dynamic elements
        var i = 1 //Global index will do just fine
        $("#clone_form").click(function() { //Here I've created a click event listener and pointed it to my html element with id = clone_form
            //When this event fires I clone my primary form using the .clone() function. Then I modify my cloned element properties with a .prop() function
            var cloned_form = $("#form_A").clone().prop("id", "cloned_"+i); //Inside .prop() I specify which attribute I want to change and a value for it
            cloned_form.find("#form_title").text("cloned_title"+i); //Here I  change a few more tags and values...
            cloned_form.find("#form_submit").prop("id", "cloned_submit_"+i);
            cloned_form.appendTo("#container_B"); //When finished, I append my cloned form to my second container
            i++; //I increase my index so I can use it in future cloning events
        });
        //When firing dynamically created elements with events, we can use the .on() function to do that (lookup jquery event delegations)
        //https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
        $(document).on('click', 'input.button-submit', function (event) { //Event type, selector and a function will do the trick
            var firstname = $(this).parent().find("#firstname").val(); //To prove we fire these events, let's grab some values from our dynamically created fields and display them
            var lastname = $(this).parent().find("#lastname").val();
            alert("Clicked: " + event.target.id + ", Hello! "+firstname+ " "+lastname); //We display our values with a simple alert box
        });
    });
```

To wrap everything together we get a very basic page that handles cloning forms and displays data on dynamically created (cloned) form "submit" events. Here is the full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            //I load my functions when document is ready (when page has finished loading)
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //I create a very simple index for my dynamic elements indexes
                var i = 1 //I didn't want to complicate things, so I made it global
                $("#clone_form").click(function() { //Here I've created a click event listener and pointed it to my html element with id = clone_form (button)
                    //When this event fires I clone my primary form using the .clone() function. I can modify my cloned element properties with a .prop() function
                    var cloned_form = $("#form_A").clone().prop("id", "cloned_"+i); //Inside .prop() I specify which attribute I want to change and a value for it
                    cloned_form.find("#form_title").text("cloned_title"+i); //Lets chnage a few more tags and values
                    cloned_form.find("#form_submit").prop("id", "cloned_submit_"+i);
                    cloned_form.appendTo("#container_B"); //When finished, lets append our cloned form to our second container
                    i++; //I increase my index so I can use it in future cloning events
                });
                //When firing dynamically created elements with events, we can use the .on() function to do that (lookup jquery event delegations)
                //https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
                $(document).on('click', 'input.button-submit', function (event) { //Event type, selector and a function will do the trick
                    var firstname = $(this).parent().find("#firstname").val(); //To prove we fire these events, let's grab some values from our dynamically created fields and display them
                    var lastname = $(this).parent().find("#lastname").val();
                    alert("Clicked: " + event.target.id + ", Hello! "+firstname+ " "+lastname); //We display our values with a simple alert box
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container_A">
          <form id="form_A">
            <div id="form_title"></div>
            <div>First name:</div><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
            <div>Last name:</div><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br>
            <input id="form_submit" class="button-submit" type="button" value="Submit!" />
            <br><br>
          </form>
        </div>
        <button id="clone_form" type="button">Clone!</button>
        <br><br>
        <div id="container_B">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's simple as that.

**EDIT:**
If you want to clone your primary form only once it gets even simpler since we already have a global index that tells us how many forms have been created so  far. Wrap your cloning part of the script inside an if statement and check if **i** (your global index) is less than 2 like this:

```
$("#clone_form").click(function() { //Here I've created a click event listener and pointed it to my html element with id = clone_form (button)
    //When this event fires I clone my primary form using the .clone() function. I can modify my cloned element properties with a .prop() function
    if (i < 2) {
        var cloned_form = $("#form_A").clone().prop("id", "cloned_"+i); //Inside .prop() I specify which attribute I want to change and a value for it
        cloned_form.find("#form_title").text("cloned_title"+i); //Lets chnage a few more tags and values
        cloned_form.find("#form_submit").prop("id", "cloned_submit_"+i);
        cloned_form.appendTo("#container_B"); //When finished, lets append our cloned form to our second container
        i++; //I increase my index so I can use it in future cloning events
    }
});
```

Now your cloning will execute only once, index adds up on first clone and when next clone button click event fires the cloning stops.

Cheers :)